# Get a CSV file containing names of files within a directory?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I am trying to figure out how to export the names of the files I have in a directory to be saved in a CSV file that I can edit in Excel. The directory looks like this:

```
$ ls
Sample_38_41_1_A01  Sample_38_41_1_A11  Sample_38_41_1_B09
Sample_38_41_1_C07  Sample_38_41_1_D05  Sample_38_41_1_E03
Sample_38_41_1_F01
```

I want each row of the CSV file to have the name of a file found in that directory. It should look like this in Excel:

```
A            B    C
1 Sample_38_41_1_A01
2 Sample_38_41_1_A11
3 Sample_38_41_1_B09 
4 Sample_38_41_1_C07 
5 Sample_38_41_1_D05
6 Sample_38_41_1_E03
7 Sample_38_41_1_F01
8 ...
```

Comment: Can you provide us more information, for example a script you're trying to use, or one you've written.  Perhaps the format of the Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your example file names don't have any double quotes or commas in them, the solution is quite simple:

```
$ 'ls' > files.csv
```

There are a couple of subtleties here:

1. You want to quote the `ls` command in case you have an alias that adds flags to it that affect the output, such as `-F`, which appends file type sigils, or `-C`, which forces multi-column output. Such aliases are quite common on modern Unix and Unix-like systems.
2. When `ls` is writing to a pipeline instead of a terminal, it prints one file name per line instead of the multi-column output you show in your question. POSIX [requires single-column output in this case](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), and GNU and BSD `ls` obey.

This CSV file won't have a header line, but Excel can cope with that; not all CSV readers can.

### But What If There *Are* Special Characters?

Double quotes and commas are special characters in CSV files, so if you try the above command on a directory containing files named using such characters, you won't get a valid CSV file.

It's not too difficult to cope with these cases.

First let's take the case of files that may only have commas in them. This is going to be a much more common case since double quotes have meaning in Unix command shells, so there is a strong disincentive to using them in file names:

```
$ 'ls' | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' > files.csv
```

These `sed` string replacement commands put double quotes at the beginning and end of each line, which prevents a CSV reader from treating commas as field separators.

Another way to achieve the same end is `perl -ne 'chomp ; print "\"$_\"\n"'`

If you really do have double-quotes in your file names, the `sed` solution extends naturally:

```
$ 'ls' | sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' > files.csv
```

That is to say, we escape any existing double-quote characters before wrapping the line in semantic quotes.

Some CSV readers handle double-quote escaping differently, treating two double-quote characters in a row as a literal double-quote:

```
$ 'ls' | sed -e 's/"/""/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' > files.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

`find * > yourfilename.csv` much easier.

Answer (score -2):

this:

```
find ~/Music -maxdepth 3 -type f -iname "*.mp3" -printf "%h,%f,%CY-%Cm-%Cd %CT,%s,%u,%M\n" > mymusic.csv
```